# Mac Mini + HP 3065 - resolution

Tags: mac, screen, mac-mini

I bought the new Mac Mini and connected it to my HP 3065 screen using the DVI cable + supplied HDMI to DVI adapter. The problem is, that the display settings enable me only very low resolutions (max 1280x800), which is unacceptable for this 30" display.

Is there any way to get the high resolution - 2560x1600? The Apple site says that it is possible somehow, but I don`t know how.

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB571LL/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter) since your monitor doesn't support Mini DisplayPort.